# Postgres stored procedure errs while parsing JSONB object

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb, stored-functions

I am trying to run the following stored procedure in Postgres:

```
...
FOR showing IN SELECT * FROM json_to_recordset(to_json(event_times)) AS show(id INTEGER, 
    times JSONB, startDate DATE, endDate DATE) LOOP
  IF showing.id > 0 THEN
    UPDATE
      event_shows
    SET
      start_date = showing.startDate, end_date = showing.endDate, times = showing.times
    WHERE
      event_id = eid AND
      id = showing.id;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO
      event_shows (event_id, start_date, end_date, times)
    VALUES
      (eid, showing.startDate, showing.endDate, showing.times);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

The values of `event_times` is `[{"times":[{"end":"13:00","start":"12:00"}],"endDate":"2020-05-19T19:45:47.121Z","startDate":"2020-05-19T19:45:47.121Z"},{"startDate":"2020-05-20T19:55:15.000Z","endDate":"2020-05-20T19:55:15.000Z","times":[{"start":"12:00","end":"13:00"}]}]`.

When I run the code, it errs at:

```
"SQL statement \"INSERT INTO\n          event_shows (event_id, start_date, end_date, times)\n        VALUES\n          (eid, showing.startDate, showing.endDate, showing.times)\"
```

The message is `null value in column \"start_date\" violates not-null constraint`. Seems like my JSONB object is not being parsed correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

The table `event_shows` is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE event_shows (
  id SERIAL,
  event_id SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES event(id),
  start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  end_date DATE NOT NULL,
  times JSONB,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Running: `PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 6.4.0) 6.4.0, 64-bit`

Comment: What type is `event_times`? And why do you think you need to call `to_json()` on it?

Comment: Please always disclose your version of Postgres. And the (minimal) exact `CREATE TABLE event_shows ...` statement. Also "stored procedure" is a function or a procedure? Typically function. Always post a complete `CREATE FUNCTION` statement to avoid ambiguities (even if it's not working).

Comment: If/when I substitute `showing.startDate` for `"2020-05-19T19:45:47.121Z"` for debugging purposes, `INSERT` works. Hence, I believe that something odd is happening while my `event_times` is being "parsed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, column names in Postgres are sensitive so whenever one uses a camelcase name, like `startDate`, it should taken in quotes. The Postgres version does not matter too much.